# Storing a text file lines into Array

Tags: c, arrays

ı am trying to take text from a file and store it into 2d array every line will be different row and every word will be different column i was thinking to store lines first then seperate words but this doesn't work quite right in the while loop its prints correctly but outside of the loop array only has last line any help?

```
    char **arr;
    arr=malloc(sizeof(int)*line);
    int a ;
    for(a=0;a<line;a++){
        arr[a]=(char*)malloc(sizeof(int)*maxword);
    }
    int i=0;
    rewind(fp);
    while(fgets(command,count, fp)!=NULL) {
        arr[i]=command;
        printf("%s",arr[i]);

        i++;

    }
```

Comment: The array of pointers should be `arr=malloc(sizeof(char*)*line);`. If you want to store the whole line, the next level of arrays should be something like `arr[a]=(char*)malloc(sizeof(char)*maxword);`, assuming `maxword` is the **maximum number of characters** including the NUL termination. Instead of `arr[i]=command;` you have to use `strcpy` or (to avoid buffer overflow) `strncpy`.

Comment: thanks for the answers solved the problem

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem here is the way you are trying to copy the input `command` string into your `arr` array of strings.  The line you have:

```c
arr[i]=command;
```

is assigning to the string pointer at `arr[i]` the value of the string pointer `command`, which is the start of the `command` string. When you then print this out *inside* the loop, it shows correctly, because you've just read in that string.

However, in each iteration of the loop, you are giving the 'next' `arr[i]` ***the same pointer*** (the start of the `command` string). So, when you then print out each `arr[i]` string when the looping has finished, each will ***point to the same string***, which will have whatever value the last-read `command` was.

Instead, inside your loop, you should replace the above line with this:

```c
strcpy(arr[i], command);
```

This will **copy the contents** of `command` to the string indexed by `arr[i]`.

Try it and see! And feel free to ask for further clarification and/or explanation.

EDIT: Also, as pointed out by **user3121023** in the comments, you need to release the memory you have allocated for `arr` *but only when you are completey done using it!* You can do this using calls to the `free` function, corresponding to each of your `malloc` calls:

```c
for(a=0;a<line;a++){
    free(arr[a]); // First, run through a loop freeing each row ...
}
free(arr); // ... and only then free the "array of row pointers!"
```

EDIT2: Oh, and I forgot! As pointed out by **Bodo** (thanks for the reminder) you must never assume that a pointer has any given size. You have:

```
arr=malloc(sizeof(int)*line);
```

which assumes that a pointer-to-char has the size of an `int`. It may do on *some* platforms, but don't ever rely on this. Use this instead:

```c
arr=malloc(sizeof(char*)*line);
```